# xpath - condition expression

Tags: xpath

I have the below document:

```
<Ships>
   <Class name = "Kongo" >
        <Ship name "Kongo" launched = "1913" />
        <Ship name = "Hiei" launched = "1914"/>
        <Ship name = "Haruna" launched = "1915" />
   </Class>
   <Class name = "North Carolina">
        <Ship name = "Washington" launched= "1941"/>
   </Class>
</Ships>
```

I need to find the years in which ships having the same name as their class were
launched. Which should be

```
/Ships/Class/Ship[..]/@launched
```

the '...' part has been omitted as it should be a condition that specifies where the ship name equals to its class name. Does anyone know how to refer to a higher level element's attribute? The query should return '1913'

Comment: You might want to correct some of your XML formatting - quite a few errors.

Comment: sorry about that, just fixed it

Comment: NP. Still a few issues, though :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Ships/Class/Ship[@name = ../@name]/@launched
```

Comment: Wouldn't `//Ship[@name = ../@name]/@launched` be equivalent? (At least in this document, where `<Ship>` does not exist elsewhere in the XML

Comment: Yes but the any-generation operator // is not normally advised as it is computationally expensive. Whilst it has its uses, I wouldn't suggest it to OPs unless they had a good reason to need it. A specific XPath is better.

Comment: @Utkanos: Thanks! Follow up question: Would you say that this depends on whether the XML-document has a DTD or XSD connected to it?

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand - you mean in reference as to whether it is advisable to use the // operator?

Comment: just one more silly question. so ../ only goes up one level? so assuming getting to the <ships> element, which is the root, should it be '.../' or '..../'? thx!!!

Comment: ../ is one level. To go two, it's ../../. To go an indeterminate number of levels up, use the ancestor:: axes. Google Xpath axes.

Comment: @Utkanos Yes, exactly. If you have a schema you can be (pretty) sure that the XML hierarchy will stay the same, which would make it safer to use the full path, whereas `//` would work even if the hierarchy would change, at the cost of performance, which might be recommended if you can't be sure that the structure will remain the same?

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand - you have a point, in that // will sometimes be more reliable in the case of a changing schema. However as a general rule you would not hope to write XSL if you were not first sure of the schema, as this could cause obvious and undesirable results. // does have its uses, as I say; if you are looking for a node with a unique ID, for example, it's acceptable. Otherwise, I tend to avoid it. I guess it comes down to taste.

Comment: @Utkanos I think we agree, I havn't worked that much with XML-traversal, and hadn't considered the performance cost of `//`, so I just wanted your opinion on best practices. My point about the lack of a schema was just that since a schema did not exist, then perhaps `//` could be used for robustness despite the cost, since we would be less sure whether the structure would change or not. If, however, a schema WAS included, then a full xpath would be much more prudent, since it's faster and, as you say, much less likely to change since a schema of the structure had been created.

Comment: @PatrikAkerstrand - agreed :)